# Border wrapping other elements when resizing window bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to wrap the last content using border, but when I resize the window border wraps above content too?

```
<div class="row">
   <div class=" col-xs-6 col-sm-3 ">
      <img src="image/1.png" class="img-responsive center-block" >
   </div>
   <div class=" col-xs-6 col-sm-3 ">
      <img src="image/2.png" class="img-responsive center-block" >
   </div>
   <div class=" col-sm-6  clearfix" id="t">
      <div class="col-xs-7 ">
         <h3>hello</h3>
         <a href="#" class="bttn3">Add</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-5 ">
         <img src="image/t.png" class="img-responsive pull-right"> 
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am using following css

`#t{
  border: 5px solid rgb(232,226,226);
}`

Answer (score 2):

I presume you mean at small screen sizes, it's not behaving as you'd like. The problem is you're not telling bootstrap how to treat that div when the screen is below 768 pixels. Try this:

`<div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-6  clearfix" id="t">`

Note I've just added the `.col-xs-12` class. Works for me in a quick test.

Comment: Such a silly mistake. Thank you very much it works fine now.

Comment: Sometimes all it takes is another pair of eyes. Glad I could help.